# Scaling out Azure web site vs Azure web role - which is faster?

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, scalability, azure-web-roles

I have implemented an asp.net web site and hosted it in Azure as a Web Role. It is a relatively simple application making use of a database.

I am interested in high availability of the web site, thus I am using scale out feature of the Web Role; instant high usage of the web site is expected (peeks), so I am interested that the scale out operation to be fast.

My question is which is better to use in order to achieve high availability - a Web Role or an Azure Website? I observed that scaling out the Web Role takes sometime (meaning about 10-15 minutes for the virtual machine to be created and started);

Is it supposed the scaling out of the Azure website to be faster?

Is there anywhere on the microsoft's azure documentation mentioned about this?

Thanks.

Comment: How quickly does traffic rise to peak in your case?

Comment: Suddenly in 5-10 minutes, can happen any time of the day, for 30-60 minutes. As frequency - once a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a few general observations that are "as of today".  Azure Websites have the following advantages

- Azure Websites definately scale much faster.  New instance comes up really quickly.
- Deployment into Websites is usually simpler and easier

However, from other perspective, Web Roles have more of an advantage when it comes to the following:

- You can get alot more control over how scaling occurs, especially if you're using services like [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com).  This is because, Web Roles are full blown VM's and one can potentially use any performance counter to input into scaling decisions
- Web Roles are not as managed as Websites, and are generally less prone to have "Azure issues".  The more managed a service is, the obviously, more possibilities there are to occur some "host-related issues"

So, what this means, is that Websites can execute scale actions faster, but with Webroles you'll know better WHEN to execute them.

Which one is more improtant to you?

HTH